# Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView when minifyEnabled true

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation

I added `navigation components` into the project. All works fine under `debug` mode. But when generate the apk, it crashes directly after tap the icon.

So I modified `minifyEnable` to `true` under `develop` to see if any clue.

Then I came across the error:

```
Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
```

I checked the questions here: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65671739/trying-to-use-navhostfragment-and-im-getting-an-error-error-inflating-class-and) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61998629/error-inflating-class-android-fragment-app-fragmentcontainerview-can-someone-te):

1. The activity is

   class AppActivity : AppCompatActivity()
2. in the **nav-graph.xml** contains `app:startDestination`.
3. Added `implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.2'`

All above don't work. Am I on the right direction? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is cased by the `Safe Args` which should not be shrinked.
So put `@Keep` in front of the `Parceable` and `Serializable` solved the issue.

https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#proguard_considerations